# Windows 8.1 will not stay connected to wireless

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

At least once a day, my Windows 8.1 (Toshiba) laptop loses all connection to the internet. This includes accessing my router through its administrative web interface. The only way to correct this has been to turn on airplane mode, then turn it off allowing the WiFi to completely restart. However, most times when I do this, it connects only for about 10 seconds then the problem repeats. While this problem is occurring, Windows still thinks it is connected.

Also, there are at least 8 other devices in the house that connect issues free, including a Windows 7 (Toshiba) laptop, and iPad, PS3, Wii, and a couple smart phones. Thus, I do not know if this is a problem with Toshiba or Windows. All software and drivers are fully up to date.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am about to smash it to pieces.

Comment: You got your drivers from Toshiba or the actual WLAN card maker? Have you tried a USB WLAN device as a short-term fix? I find that some drivers from OEM are not always the most up to date.

Comment: I have done this when I need the internet immediately. However, most of the time if I keep swapping airplane mode on and off enough times, it stays connected finally. Just super annoying.

Comment: What wifi adapter name and driver version & what router model?

Comment: Intel Wireless-N 2200, driver provided by Microsoft, version 15.10.0.12. Router is an ASUS RT-N66U

Comment: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3506&DwnldID=23493&ProductFamily=Wireless+Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+Wi-Fi+Products&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Centrino%C2%AE+Wireless-N+2200+For+Desktop&DownloadType=Software+Applications&OSFullname=Windows+8.1%2c+64-bit*&lang=eng You tried this driver from Intel yet?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds familiar, one thread here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-networking/wifi-keeps-dropping-on-windows-81/4e2b4ede-5580-46a9-a258-4c38d944d90a <-There are some good troubleshooting hints, which you probably have tried.

But I've started to suspect that there might be some sort of bug in Win8.1. For me, only when I got a new ADSL modem, finally the problem vanished. With older modem, the connection dropped constantly, and only that same "offline & back" -trick helped.